# How do I style the results in Wordpress php?

Tags: php, wordpress, styling

I have figured out how to get a Title for the archive page for the related tags/categories,
with this code:This is in my archieve. php

$object = get_queried_object(); echo $object->name;

How do I style it?

$object = get_queried_object(); echo $object->name;

I've tried

$object = get_queried_object(); echo

### $object->name;

But it keeps coming back as error, additionally, I would like to center this. Any help will be appreciated.